# AngularJS: ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to show and hide consecutive div's respectively using ng-show.

Here is my code:

***angularExample.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Fino">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="FinController as fin">
  <ul ng-repeat="emp in fin.employees" ng-show="fin.showDiv(0)">
  <li>Name:{{emp.name}}</li>
  <li>Age:{{emp.age}}</li>
  <li>Salary:{{emp.amount | currency}}</li>
  </ul> 
  <ul ng-repeat="emp in fin.employees" ng-show="fin.showDiv(1)">
  <li>Employee Name:{{emp.name}}</li>
  <li>Employee Age:{{emp.age}}</li>
  <li>Employee Salary:{{emp.amount | currency}}</li>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

***App.js***

```
var app=angular.module("Fino",[]);

app.controller("FinController",function(){
    var show=false;

    this.employees=totalemp;

    this.showDiv=function(param){
        if(param===1)
        {
            show=true;
        }
        return show;
    };

});


var totalemp=[
{
name:"abc",age:"20",amount:"120"
},
{
name:"pqr",age:"30",amount:"130"
},
{
name:"xyz",age:"40",amount:"140"
}
]
```

***Output:***
 [image]

*I am a beginner to Angular js.I am not sure as to why my first div is appearing in the output.*

Comment: My bad.......I missed adding double braces in ng-show.....It should be ng-show="{{fin.showDiv(0)}}" rather than ng-show="fin.showDiv(0)"

Comment: Nope. ng-show will evaluate expressions. No need of `{{}}` http://jsbin.com/bugavefati/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: If you add the `{{}}` it will produce the desired effect however.

Comment: @mohamedrias I edited your code and achieved the desired result by adding double braces.........http://jsbin.com/kinewudoje/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Ajay both will behave same whether you include `{{}}` or not in `ng-show`. but great to hear  that it worked for you :)

Comment: @Ajay Would you like to accept the answer for other's reference?

Comment: @mohamedrias It is not......http://jsbin.com/yirazupudu/1/edit ......Can you look at edited code......Without double braces, both divs are getting shown and, with braces, only the div which satisfies the condition gets showed......I am slightly confused as to why this is happening......As per your answer, the result should be both divs getting showed up

Comment: @Ajay Nope, you didn't edit the `this.showDiv` code. It must return true and false. Not `show` variable http://jsbin.com/koyavebuzu/2/edit Even in the jsbin which you posted few minutes before, the `this.showDiv` was modified to satisfy the condition

Comment: @mohamedrias Dunno why I am having touble getting this......Can you explain me the difference between my code i.e  http://jsbin.com/yirazupudu/1/edit and your code i.e   http://jsbin.com/koyavebuzu/2/edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75731/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-ajay).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're referring to same variable `show` in both. The variable `show` is common for both the controller so as the second loop runs, the value got changed. So it's displaying both divs

It must be:

```
this.showDiv=function(param){
        if(param===1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

EDIT:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bugavefati/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Yep, that's right. Just add `console.log(show);` in the end of `this.showDiv` function, and u'll see that the result is `false` few times and `true` all other.

Answer (score 2):

This is because AngularJS performce atleast two digest cycles. Meaning your `showDiv` function will be executed atleast twice for every ng-show directive.

You change the value `show` if `param === 1` (and never change it back). This means in the second digest cycle the variable `show` is already `true` and the first div will get shown.

To fix this you can either change the variable `show` to false if `param === 0` (inside your function) or consider returning the boolean directly (`return param === 1`). I would recommend the second approach.